# cut text after 15 full words javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, truncate

I need to cut some text after 15 words in js, I've tried to do it but only seem to find solutions that work based around certain amount of characters and not full words

```
function shorten(str, maxLen, separator = ' ') {
    if (str.length <= maxLen) return str;
    return str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(separator, maxLen));
}
```

example of solution

Comment: Please provide some code of what you did.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll need to make an effort and ask a specific question about your code.

Comment: You're basically asking how to cut up a sentence into words (and how to put it back together). The answer is String.split() (and Array.join())

Comment: in case of multiple folowing spaces `String.split(' ')` won't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split, truncate and then join

```
function shorten(str, maxLen, separator = ' ') {
    if (str.length <= maxLen) return str;
    return str.split(separator).splice(0, maxLen).join(separator);
}
```

In the case if you can have multiple spaces between words, then you can use regex to remove those spaces and then trim to remove spaces in beginning and end.

```
function shorten(str, maxLen) {
    if (str.length <= maxLen) return str;
    const trimmed_str = str.replace(/ {1,}/g," ").trim();
    return trimmed_str.split(' ').splice(0, maxLen).join(' ');
}
```

Comment: in case of several spaces between 2 words, `String.split ('')` will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex matching a space followed by one or more non space characters 15 times:

```js
let text = 'w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10' +
    ' w11 w12 w13 w14 w15 w16 w17 w18 w19 w20';
let regex = /^(( *[^ ]+){15}).*$/;
let result = text.replace(regex, '$1');
console.log('text:   "' + text + '"');
console.log('result: "' + result + '"');
```

Output:

```
text:   "w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10 w11 w12 w13 w14 w15 w16 w17 w18 w19 w20"
result: "w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 w10 w11 w12 w13 w14 w15"
```

Explanation:

- `^` - anchor string at beginning
- `( *[^ ]+)` - expect optional spaces, followed by 1+ non-space chars
- `((...){15})` - expect the preceding match in parenthesis 15 times, and capture it in a group
- `.*$` - after that catch everything to end of string (or next newlines)